# Can someone help me convert this sql query into into a laravel db query?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a sql query in my mind and I would like to use it in my project but I don't know what's the equivalent of that query in laravel.

```
SELECT * 
FROM chat 
WHERE (id_participant1 = 1 OR id_participant2 = 1)
  AND (id_participant1 = 2 OR id_participant2 = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need closures for the parenthesied queries, so it would look like this:

```
DB::table('chat')
   ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('id_participant1', 1)
            ->orWhere('id_participant2', 1);
    })
   ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('id_participant1', 2)
            ->orWhere('id_participant2', 2);
    })
   ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i try to use a variable (declared outside the function) instead of coding the value it says that the variable is undefined @aynber

Comment: If you’re trying to pass in a variable to the subqueries, you have to use the use keyword.  `where(function($query) use ($variable)...`